# fluent nhibernate calling oracle function

Tags: oracle, function, nhibernate, fluent

`i try to call an oracle function inside a package

function :

```
FUNCTION test_func (I_PARAMS               IN TPARAMS,
                O_RESPONSE_CODE        OUT VARCHAR2,
              O_RESPONSE_EXPLANATION OUT VARCHAR2)
        RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    BEGIN
            O_RESPONSE_CODE          := 0;
            O_RESPONSE_EXPLANATION   := 'Başarılı';
            return true;
    END test_func;
```

Ora test script:

```
declare
  I_PARAMS                                          TPARAMS;
  O_RESPONSE_CODE                      VARCHAR2(4);
  O_RESPONSE_EXPLANATION    VARCHAR2(500);
  reslt                    boolean;

begin
  O_RESPONSE_EXPLANATION  := ' a';
  O_RESPONSE_CODE                    := '2';

reslt := D_PKG.test_func(I_PARAMS  , O_RESPONSE_CODE ,  O_RESPONSE_EXPLANATION );
dbms_output.put_line(o_response_explanation || ' ' || o_response_code);
end;
```

it works but my fluent code does not work :S could anyone help me?

and here is it...

```
IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery("reslt := D_PKG.test_func(I _PARAMS  , O_RESPONSE_CODE ,  O_RESPONSE_EXPLANATION )")
                    .SetParameter("I_PARAMS", input, NHibernateUtil.Object)
                    .SetString("O_RESPONSE_CODE", null)
                    .SetString("O_RESPONSE_EXPLANATION", null)
                    .SetBoolean("reslt",false);

                output.RESULT = query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

here is my Parameter I_PARAMS does not exist as a named parameter

Answer (score 0):

May be `session.CreateSQLQuery("reslt := D_PKG.test_func(:I _PARAMS  , :O_RESPONSE_CODE ,  :O_RESPONSE_EXPLANATION )")`. Missed the : char?

Comment: thanks, but it does not works.
same error {System.ArgumentException: Parameter sonuc does not exist as a named parameter in...

Comment: Try query like `select D_PKG.test_func(:I _PARAMS , :O_RESPONSE_CODE , :O_RESPONSE_EXPLANATION)` or `select D_PKG.test_func(:I _PARAMS , :O_RESPONSE_CODE , :O_RESPONSE_EXPLANATION) from dual` (don't know about dual, i'm not good at oracle) and Add values only with SetParameter("NAME", Value).